# Auto-layout/width of uibutton problem in stackView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm having a UIScrollView and inside of it I got a UIStackView which I append into few UIButtons, now when i append a UIButton the size changes :\ also it doesn't has the same size + text is clipping :\ I tried to find the problem but couldn't find it :(.
Here's my code: (must say I do the auto-layout of the uiscrollview+uistackview using storyboards)

Here's a picture of the auto-layout: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHM26.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHM26.jpg

Here's a picture of how it looks like:

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ByHashtags: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var hashTagOptionsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var selectedHashtagsStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
        self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        
        insertOptionButtons()
        
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    fileprivate func insertOptionButtons() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        button.setTitle("#sport", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertIntoStackView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8394575715, green: 0.9233128428, blue: 0.9912871718, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3784077764, green: 0.6974633336, blue: 0.9678211808, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
      
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setTitle("#healing", for: .normal)
        button2.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertIntoStackView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8394575715, green: 0.9233128428, blue: 0.9912871718, alpha: 1)
        button2.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3784077764, green: 0.6974633336, blue: 0.9678211808, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        button2.layer.cornerRadius = 12

        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let button3 = UIButton()
        button3.setTitle("#morningstory", for: .normal)
        button3.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)

        
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertIntoStackView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        
        button3.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8394575715, green: 0.9233128428, blue: 0.9912871718, alpha: 1)
        button3.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3784077764, green: 0.6974633336, blue: 0.9678211808, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        button3.layer.cornerRadius = 12

        button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        hashTagOptionsStackView.alignment = .fill
        hashTagOptionsStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        hashTagOptionsStackView.spacing = 10.0
        
        
        hashTagOptionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        hashTagOptionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
        hashTagOptionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button3)
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func insertIntoStackView(_ sender: UIButton) {

        selectedHashtagsStackView.addArrangedSubview(sender)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need to show the constraints you have set on the stack view(s) in your cell prototype.

Comment: i was not able to see any UIScrollView here. Add stackview to the scrollview, and set edge constraints to scrollview content guide.When you add buttons to the stackview, just set the button's content hugging priority to required(or 1000).

Comment: @DonMag I edited the post with the constraints

Comment: @AviavSabag - link to image is invalid.

Comment: @DonMag Now it works, was invalid for some reason.. :|

Comment: @AviavSabag - OK, very confusing... First, the code you posted is putting 3 buttons in one stack view, but your image shows **one** large button and **two** smaller buttons, obviously not in the same stack view. Second, the image of your layout shows scroll views extending past the right side of the cell. Third, explain your scroll views... should each have a Horizontal stack view, containing *n* number of buttons, and each should scroll horizontally?

Comment: @DonMag I tell you what I do, I've two UIScrollViews okay? now I put into both of them UIStackViews and in the code I inserted UIButtons cause I would like to have a two scrollviews with UIButtons inside so the user can scroll and choose "hashtags", I placed stackviews inside so I can transfer from one stackview to another :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues...

This line:

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
```

does nothing, because the buttons in a stack view use auto-layout.

If you want all the buttons to have a width of 100, set your stack view's `.distribution = .fill` and give each button a width constraint:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

For your scroll views, make sure to constrain the stack view to the scroll view's `Content Layout Guide`, and constrain the stack view's Height equal to the scroll view's `Frame Layout Guide` Height.

Here's a xib that should give you (close to) what you're going for:

[image]

Note that IB doesn't like incomplete scroll views layouts, so give each stack view an Intrinsic Content Size "placeholder":

[image]

Here's the source code for the xib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="153" id="pPM-g6-WWs" customClass="ByHashtags" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="476" height="153"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="pPM-g6-WWs" id="OXE-su-1dl">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="476" height="153"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="By Hashtags" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0iV-vu-7Zu">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="10" width="103" height="20.5"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JTS-SC-VrS" userLabel="ListOfHashTags">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="40.5" width="444" height="40"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="200" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="30" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="a09-ub-dWX">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="200" height="40"/>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="a09-ub-dWX" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="nAx-F0-JiF" secondAttribute="top" id="1cC-PE-OeC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a09-ub-dWX" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="EAz-Mr-cfG" secondAttribute="height" id="Cmq-3F-kpO"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a09-ub-dWX" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="nAx-F0-JiF" secondAttribute="trailing" id="DGV-I8-KLb"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="YmK-dU-qj1"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a09-ub-dWX" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="nAx-F0-JiF" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ieC-6z-MMz"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a09-ub-dWX" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="nAx-F0-JiF" secondAttribute="leading" id="t6l-u1-8P9"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="nAx-F0-JiF"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="EAz-Mr-cfG"/>
                    </scrollView>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Trending:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WCQ-ix-GRZ">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="100.5" width="71" height="20.5"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="light" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="u2n-IY-Fdc" userLabel="HashTagsOption">
                        <rect key="frame" x="103" y="90.5" width="357" height="40"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="200" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="30" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="YxX-2S-tyP">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="200" height="40"/>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="YxX-2S-tyP" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Uns-Dw-jnK" secondAttribute="leading" id="4ZO-sx-0DL"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="Aj5-oj-mtC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YxX-2S-tyP" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Uns-Dw-jnK" secondAttribute="top" id="DE6-FD-VA3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YxX-2S-tyP" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Uns-Dw-jnK" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Gha-rq-BV7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YxX-2S-tyP" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Uns-Dw-jnK" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KXv-PA-vML"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="YxX-2S-tyP" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="6Sx-2o-tss" secondAttribute="height" id="Riu-eV-99K"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="Uns-Dw-jnK"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="6Sx-2o-tss"/>
                    </scrollView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="u2n-IY-Fdc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="JTS-SC-VrS" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="3r3-Ai-onp"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="JTS-SC-VrS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OXE-su-1dl" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="880-ZB-ECh"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="u2n-IY-Fdc" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="Kwo-76-H59"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="u2n-IY-Fdc" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="PbP-Ha-Y2v"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="0iV-vu-7Zu" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OXE-su-1dl" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="Pt2-nX-hef"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="WCQ-ix-GRZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OXE-su-1dl" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="SKF-CH-ixU"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="JTS-SC-VrS" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="T0G-Am-A6U"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="u2n-IY-Fdc" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WCQ-ix-GRZ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="YCK-v4-CBa"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="WCQ-ix-GRZ" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="u2n-IY-Fdc" secondAttribute="centerY" id="da9-N8-o27"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="JTS-SC-VrS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="0iV-vu-7Zu" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="f5p-e1-IaC"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="0iV-vu-7Zu" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OXE-su-1dl" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="tOy-83-JJx"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="hashTagOptionsStackView" destination="YxX-2S-tyP" id="y5U-sR-n3E"/>
                <outlet property="selectedHashtagsStackView" destination="a09-ub-dWX" id="HV5-3W-Hvo"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="152.17391304347828" y="84.040178571428569"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Here is sample controller and cell code:

```
class HashtagsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // register the nib for reuse
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ByHashtags", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "bhNib")
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bhNib", for: indexPath) as! ByHashtags
        return c
    }
    
}

class ByHashtags: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var hashTagOptionsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var selectedHashtagsStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
        self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        
        insertOptionButtons()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    fileprivate func insertOptionButtons() {
        
        let btns: [String] = [
            "sport", "healing", "morningstory", "another", "something", "six", "seven", "eight"
        ]
        
        btns.forEach { str in

            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.setTitle("#" + str, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
            
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertIntoStackView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8394575715, green: 0.9233128428, blue: 0.9912871718, alpha: 1)
            button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3784077764, green: 0.6974633336, blue: 0.9678211808, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            
            hashTagOptionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        hashTagOptionsStackView.alignment = .fill
        hashTagOptionsStackView.distribution = .fill
        hashTagOptionsStackView.spacing = 10.0
        
        selectedHashtagsStackView.alignment = .fill
        selectedHashtagsStackView.distribution = .fill
        selectedHashtagsStackView.spacing = 10.0

    }
    
    @objc func insertIntoStackView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedHashtagsStackView.addArrangedSubview(sender)
    }
    
}
```

and the result after tapping the first button (I gave the scroll views background colors to make it easy to see the frames):

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you very much mate, you helped me a lot(once again) really thanks for that. I really need to work from my side on autolayout but ye im still kinda new to swift :)